# Java, Selenium: Stale element exception while page reloaded after button click on WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

In the webpage I'm automating, I want to select the `checkboxes` contained by the cells of a table, based on the text value of the next cell in the same row.

But, on each click of a checkbox the page is reloaded so I'm getting a **`StaleElementException`**, after the first checkbox is checked.

```
ArrayList<WebElement> rows = (ArrayList<WebElement>)driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[contains(@class, 'configsubcell_plain')]/td[contains(@class, 'configsubcell_plain')]/table/tbody/tr"));
for (WebElement row: rows) {    
    if(row.getText().contains("Accept"))
    {           
        ArrayList<WebElement> cells =(ArrayList<WebElement>)row.findElements(By.xpath("td"));           
        int i=1;
        for (WebElement cell: cells) 
        {  
          if(i==11)//the 12 the cell contains the value "Accept"
           {
             cell.click();              //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("xmlCustomizationInput")));
        //rows = (ArrayList<WebElement>)driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[contains(@class, 'configsubcell_plain')]/td[contains(@class, 'configsubcell_plain')]/table/tbody/tr"));
          }
          i++;          
        }
    }
```

The webpage is designed with many nested tables, so I will have to use two array lists to identify my product.

After the click I tried using a `wait` condition and reinitializing the rows, but that also resulted in the same **`StaleElementException`**.

Please help me on checking all the `checkboxes` with the value **Accept** even after the page reloads after each click.

Comment: can you please provide the webpage along with html dom

Comment: the web page is an internal website. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved the issue by iterating the entire page to find the rows containing the "Accept" text and storing the position in array as below

```
int i=1,j=0,rownum=0;

if(row.getText().contains("Accept"))
{           
    ArrayList<WebElement> cells =(ArrayList<WebElement>)row.findElements(By.xpath("td"));           

    for (WebElement cell: cells) 
    {  
      if(i==11)//the 12 the cell contains the value "Accept"
       {
         row_cell[j]=rownum;                
            j++;           
      }

    }
}
```

And then i iterated directly giving the xpath with the row number stored, cell number will always be 11,so i had hardcoded the value. To make the loop wait, until the checkbox is checked, i kept it in a while loop. After the check the page will be reloaded, again the exception occurrs, i made the driver wait and re-assigned the webelement and gave continue

```
for(int l=0; l<row_cell.length; l++) {
if(row_cell[l]!=0)
{

 apath="html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[contains(@class, 'configsubcell_plain')]/td[contains(@class, 'configsubcell_plain')]/table/tbody/tr["+row_cell[l]+"]/td[11]";
 System.out.println("path is: "+apath);
 WebElement rows1;
 try
 {
rows1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(apath));`rows1.click();
while(!rows1.isSelected())`{
    System.out.println("in while");`}
 }
 catch(org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException ex)
 {
     System.out.println("inside catch");
     WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6);
       wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("xmlCustut")));
      rows1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(apath));
      continue;
 } `
```

`